# Scala: pattern matching on nested type hierarchies

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, hierarchical

Let's say I have

```
sealed trait AlphaNumericChar

sealed trait AlphaChar
case object A extends AlphaNumericChar with AlphaChar
case object B extends AlphaNumericChar with AlphaChar

sealed trait NumericChar
case object One extends AlphaNumericChar with NumericChar
case object Two extends AlphaNumericChar with NumericChar
```

This structure allows me to pattern match on `AlphaNumericChar` and get all `A,B,One,Two` and similarly pattern match on `AlphaChar` and `NumericChar` and get only the relevant objects.

What it doesn't allow me, is to write:

```
def foo(x: AlphaNumericChar) = ???
def bar(x: AlphaChar) = foo(x)
```

ie, proxy calls to `foo` for only certain types. I can of course write instead:

```
def baz(x: AlphaNumericChar with AlphaChar) = foo(x)
```

and that would work but that's perhaps a bit ugly.

Alternative is to make `AlphaChar` and `NumericChar` extend `AlphaNumericChar` but that would mess with my pattern matches on `AlphaNumericChar` as I will now have to handle `_:AlphaChar` and `_:NumericChar` in addition to my case objects which is undesirable.

Is there a way of somehow having the best of two worlds? ie.

- The exhaustive list of pattern match entries on `AlphaChar`/`NumericChar` has only two elements.
- The exhaustive list of pattern match entries on `AlphaNumericChar` has only two elements.
- I can have the `bar` function above working without resorting to the `baz` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Extending AlphaNumericChar shouldn't be a problem. Something like this works fine:

```
sealed trait AlphaNumericChar

sealed trait AlphaChar extends AlphaNumericChar

case object A extends AlphaChar
case object B extends AlphaChar

sealed trait NumericChar extends AlphaNumericChar

case object One extends NumericChar
case object Two extends NumericChar

def foo(x: AlphaNumericChar) = x match {
  case One => println("hi")
  case Two => println("bye")
  case A => println("foo")
  case B => println("bar")
}

def bar(x: AlphaChar) = foo(x)

def aThirdFunction(y: NumericChar) = y match {
  case One => println("eggs")
  case Two => println("beans")
}

foo(One)  // hi
foo(Two)  // bye
foo(A)    // foo
foo(B)    // bar
bar(A)    // foo
bar(B)    // bar
aThirdFunction(One) // eggs
aThirdFunction(Two) // beans
```

Unless I've misunderstood what you want?

Comment: yes I think I wasn't clear enough. I am talking about the compiler generated exhaustive list of cases. Your solution which I believe is my second option, works but the compiler should warn you about case exhaustivity in `foo`.

Comment: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/iaFRC4BARkuIJSeF7I6fgw this doesn't complain, but if you delete one of the case statements (and its corresponding test) Scastie complains that your matches aren't exhaustive.

Comment: interesting. I wrote my example with `2.12.10`. But I just tested your example with `2.12.10` and it's fine with that too. Guess it's not a problem with the compiler then and one with the IntelliJ plugin that tries to auto-generate my cases.

Comment: Yeah IntelliJ isn't perfect. Let me know if you have any other queries/concerns.